# Selecting rows whose foreign rows ONLY match a single value

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Say I have two tables --`people` and `pets`-- where each person may have more than one pet:

`people`:

```
+-----------+-------+
| person_id | name  |
+-----------+-------+
|         1 | Bob   |
|         2 | John  |
|         3 | Pete  |
|         4 | Waldo |
+-----------+-------+
```

`pets`:

```
+--------+-----------+--------+
| pet_id | person_id | animal |
+--------+-----------+--------+
|      1 |         1 | dog    |
|      2 |         1 | dog    |
|      3 |         1 | cat    |
|      4 |         2 | cat    |
|      5 |         3 | dog    |
|      6 |         3 | tiger  |
|      7 |         3 | tiger  |
|      8 |         4 | tiger  |
|      9 |         4 | tiger  |
|     10 |         4 | tiger  |
+--------+-----------+--------+
```

I'm trying to select the people who ONLY have `tiger`s as pets. Obviously the only one that fits this criteria is `Waldo`, since `Pete` has a `dog` as well... but I'm having some trouble writing the query for this.

The most obvious case is `select people.person_id, people.name from people join pets on people.person_id = pets.person_id where pets.animal = "tiger"`, but this returns `Pete` and `Waldo`.

It would be helpful if there was a clause like `pets.animal ONLY = "tiger"`, but as far as I know this doesn't exist.

How could the query be written?

Comment: Don't forget to consider whether a person might have no pets, or multiple pets that are all tigers.

Comment: You want people who don't have things that aren't tigers as pets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select people.person_id, people.name 
   from people 
   join pets on people.person_id = pets.person_id 
  where pets.animal = "tiger" 
    AND people.person_id NOT IN (select person_id from pets where animal != 'tiger');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select p.person_id
from pets p
group by p.person_id
having max(animal) = 'tiger' and min(animal) = 'tiger';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct person_id
from pets 
where animal = "tiger"
intersect
select distinct person_id
from pets 
where animal = "tiger" 
and person_id not in 
(select person_id from pets where animal <> "tiger")
```

You can use `intersect` to select a person who only has tiger as his pet.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM people pp
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pets pt
   WHERE pt.person_id = pp.person_id
   AND pt.animal = 'tiger'
   )
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pets pt
   WHERE pt.person_id = pp.person_id
   AND pt.animal <> 'tiger'
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

*If* every person was guaranteed to have at least one pet, then the query could be as simple as:

```
select name
  from people
 where not exists (select 1
                     from pets
                    where pets.person_id = people.id and
                          pets.animal   != 'tiger')
```

Or: return the people for whom there is no record that is not a tiger.

NOT EXISTS is executed as a very efficient anti-join, in which each row from people would be rejected as soon as a single non-tiger pet was found.

Comment: Thank you, David! Didn't know about "not exists". What if some people have no pets, though? What would change?

Comment: In that case you'd want to check that the person had at least one tiger as well, using an EXISTS predicate.